# Is there a polyfill for SVGs used as CSS backgrounds?

Tags: css, svg, polyfills

I would like to use SVG and not to have to create a PNG fallback every time. Is the an easy solution to this problem? I have looked at these projects but can't tell whether they support it:

http://sie.sourceforge.jp/

http://code.google.com/p/svgweb/

Comment: Just tried the `http://sie.sourceforge.jp/` script and it does /not/ support it.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. This would be nice to have...

Answer (score 0):

try GruntIcon - http://github.com/filamentgroup/grunticon

> grunticon takes a folder of SVG files (typically, icons that you've
>   drawn in an application like Adobe Illustrator), and outputs them to
>   CSS in 3 formats: svg data urls, png data urls, and a third fallback
>   CSS file with references to regular png images, which are also
>   automatically generated and placed in a folder.
>
> grunticon also generates a small bit of JavaScript and CSS to drop
>   into your site, which asynchronously loads the appropriate icon CSS
>   depending on a browser's capabilities, and a preview HTML file with
>   that loader script in place.

Answer (score -1):

There's quite a number of SVG polyfills:

https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills#svg

Please try them and update your initial question with the results for each.

Comment: I know that list. But I can't find a CSS polyfill. Can you?